# java String query

Tags: java, substring, lastindexof

i have a requirement i needed to be figure out .

consider a string for ex "/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX ......n times "

I needed to get the second set of string from this string,last string set,with out last string set rest of the String.
xx mentioned in example can be a-z,A-z,0-9,and spaces also.
i am able to get last string set,with out last string set rest of the String.
please let me know how to get 2nd string set.

```
              String a ="/WorkGroups/Testing Test WG 1/R14A";
              int position = a.lastIndexOf('/');
              System.out.println(position);//Print 28 
              System.out.println(a.substring(0,position));//print /WorkGroups/EriDoc Test WG 1
              System.out.println(a.substring(position+1));//print R14A
```

how to get only Testing Test WG 1 ?

Comment: a little bit more clarification please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code -

```
    String a ="/WorkGroups/Testing Test WG 1/R14A";
    System.out.println(a.split("/")[2]);
```

Output -

```
 Testing Test WG 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] arr = yourString.split("/");
arr[whateverIndexYouWant]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option :

```
System.out.println(a.substring(12, 28)
```

First parameter is an index of a start element, second parameter is an index of last element.